# kaminari pagination problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

Very simple pagination set up giving me the following error:

```
    NoMethodError in Projects#index

Showing /users/MasterControl/div/ikon/app/views/projects/index.html.erb where line #32 raised:

undefined method `current_page' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #32):

29: <br />
30: 
31: 
32: <%= paginate @products %>
Rails.root: /users/MasterControl/div/ikon

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
kaminari (0.12.4) lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb:21:in `paginate'
app/views/projects/index.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_projects_index_html_erb___59843737_2173384980_0'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `_render_template'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:93:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:261:in `retrieve_response_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:192:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:192:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:8:in `index'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `_run__46567664__process_action__199225275__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Controller:

```
def index
@projects = Project.order("created_at").page(params[:page]).per(2)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @projects }
end
```

end

Index view:

```
<%= paginate @products, :window => 3 %>
```

Not sure what the problem is here find it hard to understand the error, I'll be greatful for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@products != @projects`

Either you're using the wrong view or you've just fumbled the collection name.

Comment: You're really not. Your controller sets `@projects` and your view tries to paginate `@products`. Similarly your backtrace shows that the template in use is `projects/index.html.erb` but it's trying to paginate `@products` (using different code than your description of it).